# PHP - Broken variable content

Tags: php

as the subject, I have a problem with the content of a variable.
Within into this variable is inserted a `base64` of a file (extracted from an xml) and PHP the base64 to save the file in the filesystem.
Everything is fine as long as there are small files (about 10MB) ... however the `base64` with a file bigger the `base64` seems to be "broken" after 9999993 characters.
I say seems because if I go to the debug display the value of the variable I see all of the `base64` string.

The problem is not in saving the file, because the file is created and saved correctly, but the content of the variable. Are there any limits to be set on php.ini? Or are there ways to remedy the problem? I also tried to split the string in chunks or in an array, but the problem remains.

I put the code I use to extract data from XML:

```
    $reader = new XMLReader(); 

    if (!$reader->open($GLOBALS['conf']['filepath'] . '/' . $xmlfile)) { 
        print "Error to open XML: $xmlfile\n"; 
    } else { 
        while ($reader->read()) { 
            $name = $reader->name; 
            $type = $reader->nodeType; 
            if (($type == XMLReader::ELEMENT) && in_array($name, $allowedNodes)) { 
                $xml = $reader->readOuterXml(); 

                $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8'); 
                $xml = simplexml_import_dom($doc->importNode($reader->expand(), true)); 

                //Other code
            } 
        } 
    }
```

Note:
the variable `$allowedNodes` is a variable saved in a configuration file, so you do not see its value.

Thanks for the answers

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? Did you try to change `memory_limit` directive in the _php.ini_ configuration file?

Comment: `memory_limit` value is 512M; PHP version is 5.3.1

Comment: how much does your process take ?

Comment: How can I check PHP process? I have an PC with Windows OS

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to substitute base64 with gzcompress?

I had a similar problem time ago, and I used it with good results. I did a small benchmark and memory is not a great problem.

Comment: XML file is created from a procedure .NET. Is possible create a gzcompressed base64 code?

Comment: Yes. I compressed XML nodes after processing them. I used DomDocument instead of XMLReader, but the result is not different.

Comment: OK... is there olther solutions? because  use gzcompress forces me to change the software requirements. Another solution can be subdivide in chunk in XML?

Comment: Yes. You can subdivide the XML tree in whatever parts you want.